# How to restrict access to my site using htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess, security, htpasswd

**How to disallow access to site except me?**

Comment: ok, if i rent just hosting?

Comment: You can edit your questions if you want to add info or reword the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of variety: if you have a static IP address you could block all IP addresses except yours:

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Just change xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to be your IP address.

Answer (score 2):

(on Apache Server)
**Steps**

- Choose the directory you wish to protect  You wish to protect the whole site then chose "public_html". Also chose a directory e.g. "../password" to store the password in.
- Create a file **.htaccess** and **.htpasswd**
- Edit **.htaccess** with your favourite editor to contain the following:

> AuthUserFile /path/to/password/.htpasswd
>
> AuthGroupFile /dev/null
>
> AuthName "Authentication Query Name"
>
> AuthType Basic

- place **.htaccess** in to be protected folder
- Edit **.htpasswd** to contain the username and passwords. Syntax [username]:[md5-encrypted-password] Use a [generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) to make the encryption e.g.

  > foobar:Fkb3n2r1vsba
- place **.htpasswd** in chosen directory and make sure you change the directories permission so only the server may access e.g. run chmod g+r,g+x,o-r,o-x password

Comment: Why do people still use basic authentication instead of digest?

Comment: According to the [Apache website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth_digest.html) "This module implements HTTP Digest Authentication. However, it has not been extensively tested and is therefore marked experimental."

Comment: @John: I have a feeling that documentation hasn't been updated in a long time. Netscape 7 was released 6 years ago, and pretty much all browsers currently in use support HTTP Digest. See the 2.2 documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_auth_digest.html

Comment: Ahhh, the wonders of having multiple versions of your software's documentation. :/

Comment: The sad thing is, whenever you search for Apache documentation/mods/features, the 1.0 documentation is what shows up on Google. So then you have to go to the 1.0 documentation and click on the little link up top that tells you to check out the 2.2 docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you run an Apache server just make a [.htpasswd](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) file and upload it to your main directory.

Answer (score 0):

I once came up with a solution I call .htaccess maintenance mode.
It uses mod_rewrite, restricts the site to your IP address, and redirects other people to another URL.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.1\.100
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/403\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/403.html [R=307,L]
```

A little explanation:
The first line checks the IP address. The third one redirects the user to the 403.html page. Basically it would redirect all pages to 403.html, including 403.html - the second line prevents that so users can't go into an endless redirect loop.